# How to randomly choose between two choices

Tags: android

Let's say I have to choices and a button that randomly picks one of those choises:

- I like Android
- I like iOS

How do I randomly pick the answer using the button?

Comment: [Maybe a random number](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F6%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FRandom.html&ei=M29FU_HuEMaiyAGbroGIAQ&usg=AFQjCNFj1uzG5UJN8Xu2XXHgD7n3dQ84Zw&sig2=S-I6kZlIkq7LqzZ1E6nUWA&bvm=bv.64507335,d.aWc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `button`'s `onClick()` `method`:

```
Random rand=new Random() 
int x = rand.nextInt(2);
if(x == 0)
  //  choose answer 1
else
//   choose answer 2
```

You can use `Math` library too:

```
int x = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? 0:1;
if(x == 0)
  //  choose answer 1
else
//   choose answer 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but it seems to be giving only the "0" value, I have implemented it like this:

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random rand=new Random();
                int x = rand.nextInt(1);
                if(x == 0) {
                    b.setText("Test A");
                } else {
                    b.setText("Test B");
                }
            }

Comment: ah, sorry write like this: int x = rand.nextInt(2);

I edited my answer too. The specified value is exclusive. so this should work.

Comment: The random api reference can be found here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same type, in this case strings you can do something like:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(string1);
list.add(string2);
ect..
list.shuffle();
list.get(0);
```

This will put all the string values into an `ArrayList`, shuffle the list, and then return the first element which will be random and different each time you call `.shuffle()`